# wxGTK+ wxComboBox deselection

Tags: python, gtk, wxpython, wxwidgets

When creating wx.ComboBox under Windows you can specify `wxCB_READONLY` to let users select from **only** proposed options. But you can **clear** selection by:

```
combo.SetSelection(wx.NOT_FOUND)
```

But under linux (wxGTK) the option is deselected on creation, but once selected in cannot be cleared. Not by any of following:

```
combo.SetSelection(wx.NOT_FOUND)
combo.SetValue('')
```

Is it possible to do this anyhow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, setting the value to an empty string works for me on Arch Linux:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        choices = ["", "1", "2", "3"]
        self.choices = choices
        self.cbo = wx.ComboBox(self, value="1", choices=choices)
        btn = wx.Button(self, label="Reset")
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onReset)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.cbo, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onReset(self, event):
        """"""
        print "resetting"
        self.cbo.SetValue("")


########################################################################
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="CombBox")
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        self.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: But you added '' selection to the list - does it mean it is _selectable_ by the user? When I do not add such choice, under MSW I can programmatically deselect ComboBox, but user cannot select _deselected_ state.

Comment: I tried it both ways and it worked even when "" isn't in the list.

Comment: Well '' does not work on SUSE wxGTK+.
But I'll have to stick with this workaround - to add '' to list.